# Getting xargs: unterminated quote when trying to find text in files

Tags: bash, grep, xargs

I'm using Mac 10.9.5 with bash shell.  I'm trying to search for instances of text within a group of files, but for some reason, in one particular directory, I get this bizarre "Unterminated quote" error ...

```
Daves-MacBook-Pro:sbadmin davea$ find src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/ -name "*" | xargs grep 'addresses' > /tmp/addr
xargs: unterminated quote
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That happens because one of the filenames contains a quote and is passed to `xargs` as-is. That means `xargs` is run like `xargs grep 'addresses' > /tmp/addr some file'name` — and there is an unterminated `'` here.

The actual problem is that you're using  `find | xargs`. That's something you really don't want to do, even if it looks tempting.

There are a few solutions to this problem:

1. Use the `-print0` option for `find` and `-0` for `xargs`:

   ```
   find src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/ -name "*" -print0 | xargs -0 grep 'addresses' > /tmp/addr
   ```

   This is the recommended way to pipe from `find` to `xargs` because it can deal with any filename, even those containing newlines.

   Note that using `-name "*"` is superfluous. You should also consider using `-type f` to filter only files. And you could, of course, call a program from within `find`, too:

   ```
   find … -type f -exec grep 'addresses' {} \; > /tmp/addr
   ```

   But this is also not recommended. See the second option:
2. Use a more efficient approach altogether – recursive `grep`ing with the `-r` option:

   ```
   grep -r 'addresses' src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/ > /tmp/addr
   ```